# Phonegap Vue js Android uploading CAMERA image to API server

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, android-camera, phonegap

I'm trying to upload picture taken by Android Camera (cordova-plugin-camera). My code for that is

```
takePicture () {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(result => {
    this.newUnit.addedPic = true
    this.newUnit.image = result
  }, error => {
    alert(error);
  },
  {
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  });
},
```

In my *this.newUnit.addedPic* I got the path like:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../1234.jpg
```

How can I use it to upload the picture to server from mobile app?
In my web part I use FormData to upload the picture.

I was trying to do it by FileTransfer but I get error code 1:

```
let win = r => {alert(`win`)}
    let fail = error => {
      alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
      console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
      console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = this.newUnit.image.substr(this.newUnit.image.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

    var params = {};
    params.name = "test";
    params.creator = 3;

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(this.newUnit.image, encodeURI("http://myserver/api/v0/units/"), win, fail, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. The problem was because of empty headers and http method.

```
  var headers = { 'Authorization':`Token ${token}` };
  options.headers = headers;

  options.httpMethod= "POST";
  options.chunkedMode = true;`
```